# How to check for null in Scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

How can we check for null in Scala.js?
I'm working with JavaScript library and have method that can return object or null. I've tried to use js.undefined like this

```
if(node != js.undefined){
  global.console.log("node is object")
} else global.alert("Please select node.")
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, you can simply do:

```
if (node != null) {
  global.console.log("node is object")
} else global.alert("Please select node.")
```

Check all the available types here: https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. But you give me a direction. This should be if(node != null)

Comment: Cool, glad to be helpful -- I've updated the answer using the correct way.